# Dependency injection in .Net 5 application using configuration file

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, reflection, ioc-container

I have used Microsoft Unity container for dependency injection with .Net framework where an interface and its required implementation class can be registered and mapped using a configuration file and can be resolved at runtime. Configuration is as shown below,

[image]

I am trying to do the same with .Net5 ASP Core application where it is possible to register programmatically in startup.cs like,

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
services.AddScoped<IDataProvider,DataProvider>()
}
```

But couldn't find a way to register it from configuration-file/appsettings.json. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I also want to do same thing. Is there any way to achieve dynamically using appsetting

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that out of the box. You could write your own logic that loads all contracts and implementations using reflections and register it in container using some custom defined format in your `appsettings.json` file.

I strongly discourage you to do this because mapping your contracts and implementations in `.json` file that is not tracked by symbol rename operation will cause your DI container to break anytime you rename one of your services.